# Banner slide In Venia PWA With Magento2

Tags: magento2, pwa, banner-slider, venia

I want to display Banner slider on my PWA homepage which is added in magento2.

Please help.

Comment: check this out https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262845/image-slider-for-pwa-studio

Comment: @Chikku I want to use the slider images added in the magento2 backend.

Comment: you need to define a graphql query and call that in ur code which will give u the image path, image href url. Iterate that and add the images and href url